# make "sumo 0.17.1" on ubuntu 13.10

Tags: c++, linux, ubuntu

I installed and tested v0.19.1 successfully before, however, I needed to downgrade to 0.17.1 in order to run some example in omnetpp's veins simulator.

Whenever I run the "make" command,  I get the following error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: ./utils/foxtools/libfoxtools.a(MFXMutex.o): undefined reference to symbol 'pthread_mutexattr_settype@@GLIBC_2.2.5'
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[3]: *** [sumo-gui] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/maamoun/pkgs/sumo-0.17.1/src'
make[2]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/maamoun/pkgs/sumo-0.17.1/src'
make[1]: *** [all] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/maamoun/pkgs/sumo-0.17.1/src'
make: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
```

What am I missing?!

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved, had to install libproj-dev and include proj in the ./configure using the --with-proj-includes=DIR

[EDIT] after 15 minutes of making, same error raised again!!!